# SpatialLines with determined distance

Tags: r, geospatial

I have spatial point coordinates in a matrix, and I need create (n) spatial lines with 100km of distance from the point coordinate using intervals of 1°.

How do I determine distance in kilometer using `SpatialLines` function from `sp` package? How do I determine regular intervals with 1°?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want circles around each point (such that the distance is 100 km)? What are the 'regular intervals'? Are these distances between lines? Between nodes?

Comment: Not necessarily a circle, because my intention is not use the circunference, but the radius of circle and the values for these radius in regular intervals of 1º. For this, I need create a line with 100 km from the point. After, I need replicate this line in regular intervals of 1º, until complete 360º.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
library(geosphere)
library(raster)

pt <- cbind(0,0)
d <- destPoint(pt, 0:360, 1000000)
s <- spLines(d)

plot(s)
```

for 10 degree steps:

```
d <- destPoint(pt, seq(0, 360, 10), 1000000)
s <- spLines(d)

plot(s)
points(d)
```